# Need help for background-size property

Tags: html, css, background

So I want to make my website have an initial first background sort of like the one on [this](http://hackumbc.org) website. For some reason, the picture is way too big and I can't resize it with any position property or even the background-size property regardless of everything I have tried for the past 2+ days. I also need it to be visible through the transparent nav-bar I have. I would then continue all the content of the webpage underneath the background. Also, I am new to this website so I'm not sure how to insert a random image to serve as an example of the problem, but you can see in the snippet where I inserted the image as the last piece of code in the HTML.

Here is my code:

```css
/**********BODY GENERAL**********/
body {
 margin: 0;
}
strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}
/*********NAVIGATION*********/
nav {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 1em;
 grid-auto-rows: auto;
 text-align: center;
 align-items:center;
 background: /*rgba(255, 51, 0, .95);
 */
 list-style-type: none;
 z-index: 10;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 nav {
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 1em;
 }
}
.menu1 {
 grid-column: 1;
}
.menu2 {
 grid-column: 2;
}
.logo {
 grid-column: 3;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 28px;
    width:500px;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 7vh;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 color: #000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.menu3 {
 grid-column: 4;
}
.menu4 {
 grid-column: 5;
}
/**************HOVER ANIMATION**************/
div > a {
 font-family: 'Raleway';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
}
div > a:hover {
 color: #000;
}
div > a:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1px;
 bottom: -4px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #000;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
 transform: scaleX(0);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
div > a:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
 transform: scaleX(1);
}
/**********MAIN HEADER***********/

header {
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


 #header-div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(Images/BkgImg/HSNCT%202018%205th%20in%20Nation.jpg) no-repeat center;
    position: absolute;
     z-index: -5;
     background-size: 275px 125px !important;

}

.titel-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

/**********BODY*****************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Centennial It's Academic</title>
 <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav class="container">
   <div class="menu1">
    <a class="navLinks" href="#home">Home</a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu2">
    <a class="navLinks" href="#upcoming">Tournaments</a>
   </div>
   <div class="logo">
    <p>It's Academic</p>
   </div>
   <div class="menu3">
    <a class="navLinks" href="#history">History</a>
   </div>
   <div class="menu4">
    <a class="navLinks" href="#faq">Contact Info</a>
   </div>
  </nav>
        
<!-- Background Image -->
  <div id="header-div">
    <img src="Images/BkgImg/It's%20Ac%20semi%20finals%202017-18%20%20(8).JPG">
</div>
        
        
 </header>
    
    <p> askdfhkjsdhfl;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add a background-size: cover. Remove your div and img tags and then wrap your header tags with a div and add a class bg-img to it. Then add this following CSS:

```
.bg-img {
background: url(''https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508781015212-46d58946bb05?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=39b69f4b9e54ea449f90e3d714bf9215&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: @SathwikYanamaddi hello, check this out on my codepen and let me know if this is what you're looking to do. https://codepen.io/trace751/pen/rKjvLz

Comment: Yup, that's perfect. The words would then go under the background.

Comment: @SathwikYanamaddi awesome. Please mark it as answered if this has answered your question :)